# The Equivalent Condition of the Weak Law of Large Numbers When Random Variables Are Uniformly Bounded

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

When the random variable $\{X_n,n\ge1\}$ satisfies the uniformly bounded condition, why does
$$
\frac{1}{n^2}\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k\right)\rightarrow0
$$
become a necessary and sufficient condition for the establishment of the weak law of large numbers?
From Chebyshev's law of large numbers, we can easily use the above conditions to deduce that the law of large numbers holds. So why is this condition necessary?

Comment: When $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d.
$$
n^{-1}\operatorname{Var}\!\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)=\operatorname{Var}(X_1).
$$
The average "converges" to $0$ if $X_1$ is a constant.

Comment: It is $\text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}X_k\right)\to0$ not $\frac{1}{n}\text{Var}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}X_k\right)$

Comment: If $|X|\le c$ then $\text{Var}(X) \le c^2$

Comment: @Henry thanks! If $\{X_n\}$ are not i.i.d.,  why does $Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k)\rightarrow 0$ still hold true?

Comment: It need not (you deleted "independent and identically distributed" after my comment).  Suppose all the $X_k$ are equal to each other: then $\text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}X_k\right) = \text{Var}(X_i)$ while $\frac{1}{n}\text{Var}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}X_k\right)=n\text{Var}(X_i)$

Comment: @Henry : If your comments are intended to answer the question, you should post them as answers.  In general, question-and-answer pages should be "self-contained" in that they should not require reading comments for essential information"; questions should not be answered in comments.

Comment: @PeterO. My comments have not answered this question.  In any case there are a group of users who react negatively to *any* answers to short questions.  Rather than provoke them, I often prefer to use the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $(X_n)$ are uniformly bounded and let $Y_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mathbb E[X_i])/n$. Then $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is also uniformly bounded and so is $(Y_n^2)_{n\geqslant 1}$. In particular, $(Y_n^2)$ is uniformly integrable.

The weak law of large numbers is, by definition, the convergence in probability of $Y_n\to 0$, which is equivalent to $Y_n^2\to 0$ in probability.

Now we use the following fact: convergence in $\mathbb L^1$ of $(Y_n^2)$ to $0$ is equivalent to (convergence in probability of $(Y_n^2)_n$ to $0$ and uniform integrability of $(Y_n^2)_n$), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2822454/9849).

An other way to see this is that if $\lvert X_n\rvert\leqslant C$ almost surely, then letting $Y_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mathbb E[X_i])/n$ , we have $\lvert Y_n\rvert\leqslant C$. If $Y_n\to 0$ in probability, then
$$
\operatorname{Var}(Y_n)\leqslant \mathbb E\left[Y_n^2\right]=\mathbb E\left[Y_n^2\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert Y_n\rvert>\delta\}}\right]+\mathbb E\left[Y_n^2\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert Y_n\rvert\leqslant\delta\}}\right]
\leqslant C^2\mathbb P\left(\lvert Y_n\rvert>\delta\right)+\delta^2.
$$